Tao: Positive/negative real numbers are defined as positively/negatively bounded away Cauchy sequences. Those who start negative and turn positive -?
Quote from Tao's Analysis 1:

Definition 5.4.3 A real number $x$ is
said to be positive  if and only if it can be written
as $x = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$  for some Cauchy sequence
$(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$  which is positively bounded away from
zero.  $x$ is said to be negative  if and only
if it can be written as $x = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ for some
sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$  which is negatively bounded
away from zero.

Positively bounded sequences were defined as entirely positive sequences. Negatively bounded sequences were defined as entirely positive sequences. Then what about Cauchy sequences that start negative and become positive further down the line? Or vice versa? Are they positive/negative/undefined?

The definition does not say for all Cauchy sequences, only for some Cauchy sequences.

Notice that any Cauchy sequence converging to a positive number must have a positive tail eventually so you can just take the tail to be your Cauchy sequence for the definition

First, remember that one real number can be represented by infinitely many equivalent Cauchy sequences. So as long as you can find one of them that has the required property, that number meets the definition.
Second, you can extend the definition to apply to almost all Cauchy sequences by adding the word "eventually". That is, if a Cauchy sequence is eventually positively bounded away from zero (meaning that only finitely many terms are not bounded in that way) then it represents a positive number. Proving this is quite easy since removing those terms gives you a sequence that represents the same real number but which satisfies the original definition.
If a Cauchy sequence cannot be bounded away from zero, then it must converge to zero, and hence it represents zero.
